# WebStorm /usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=55834 --nolazy app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, ampersand

I am creating an app in WebStorm for a single page web application using modularisation. I am using node with an ampersand framework and assemble browserify and watchify.

When I try to debug my app.js I get this error:-

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=55834 --nolazy app.js
Debugger listening on port 55834
/Users/tori/WebstormProjects/JSProject2_7March/node_modules/ampersand-   view/node_modules/events-mixin/node_modules/component-event/index.js:1
tion (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var bind = window.add
                                                                ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tori/WebstormProjects/JSProject2_7March/node_modules/ampersand-view/node_modules/events-mixin/node_modules/component-event/index.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tori/WebstormProjects/JSProject2_7March/node_modules/ampersand-view/node_modules/events-mixin/index.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone shed some light on what this error means?

Comment: `ReferenceError: window is not defined at Object.` Looks like you're trying to run client-side code on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your javascript using Node.js. But 'window' can't be used in server-side scripts executed by Node.js. It is only defined in client-side javascript, i.e. when running in the browser via a tag in the rendered HTML, not the Javascript API engine running on the server. Please include your app.js in HTML file (via `<script src="path/to/app.js">` tag) and then debug your HTML using Debug in .html file right-click menu